# Firebase email generation

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I've successfully built a webapp with firebase. I am trying to build something like Groupon where when you claim an offer an email is generated with the details of your purchase.

How can this be achieved?

I've looked into nodemailer so far.

Webapp is running with angular + angularfire2. Android app has also been created so the solution has to be compatible on all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

You can follow [this sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/email-confirmation) to help you.

You have to add a trigger in your database to know when an offer is claimed and send the email on this trigger.

[Other samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples).